# When it makes sense to use Reactor Processors?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

When it makes sense to use Reactor Processors?

According to the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) under [Do I Need a Processor?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_do_i_need_a_processor), I should consider first whether:

> Could an operator or combination of operators fit the bill?
>   Could a "generator" operator work instead?

But it's not very clear in which use cases I should use processors rather than generator and combination of operators.

Comment: An answer to this question may try to expand the meaning, but one obvious understanding is not to recreate processors for already existing operators, i.e. it would undesirable that you had a new processor to do map, filter, flatmap, etc.